Preferred state of motion from topology of certain spacetimes
A (1+1)-dimensional spacetime where the spatial dimension wraps around on itself (so it has the topology of $E^1\times S^1$) has a preferred state of motion, even though it is everywhere locally identical to Minkowski space: only in one frame do the lines of simultaneity wrap up into circles. A hypothetical observer in such a spacetime could send out a light pulse both ahead of and behind them, and upon receiving the signals again after the light pulses have traveled around the universe, they could calculate their speed relative to the preferred frame.
Is this a generic feature of spacetimes where the spatial shape of the universe is a compact manifold?
Edit: in addition to the accepted answer, I found "The twin paradox in compact spaces" which has some relevant info for anyone interested.

Topology alone does not lead to existence of such “preferred state of motion”. For example, two dimensional de Sitter space has the same topology $E^1\times S^1$ yet it is a maximally symmetric spacetime, meaning all inertial trajectories could be related by isometries.
Depending on viewpoint, the preferred state of motion from the question can be seen as a generic feature of ultrastatic spacetimes,  that are direct product $\mathcal{T} \times \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is 1D Euclidean space with timelike metric signature (“time”) and $\mathcal{S}$ is Riemannian manifold with spacelike metric (“space”). Such spacetimes always have timelike Killing vector field (KVF), moreover its integral curves are geodesics so this KVF represents an inertial reference frame.
But appearance of even single KVF is a rarity not a generic feature if we choose manifold “at random”.
If the number of spatial dimensions is greater than one, then a generic spatial manifold would not give rise to any additional KVF (independent of the compactness of $\mathcal{S}$), meaning that the spacetime has a preferred state of motion. Disappearance of the preferred reference frame could the be seen  as an “accidental” enhancement of spacetime symmetries to include boosts for some special choices of $\mathcal{S}$.
